# Does the length of a prediction interval decrease with sample size?

Tags: regression, prediction-interval

For a general prediction interval given by $x_{0}^T\hat{\beta} \pm t_{n-p,\alpha/2}\times s \sqrt{1+x_{0}^T(X^TX)^{-1}x_{0}} $, I have been taught that as n tends to infinity we can approximate this by $x_{0}^T\hat{\beta} \pm z_{\alpha/2} \times s$ because $1+ x_{0}^T(X^TX)^{-1}x_{0}$ becomes close to 1. My intuition is that, as the t-distribution has heavier tails than the Normal, this means that the prediction interval should decrease in length as the sample size increases. Is this true?

Comment: The sense of "$n$ tends to infinity" needs to be made precise, but we may take it that the rows of $X$ are iid realizations of some random variable.  Although the *expected* length of this prediction interval decreases, its actual length may bounce around and sometimes increase as more data are included.

Comment: @Michael are you suggesting at the outset that the prediction interval shrinks to $0$?  That's not the case.  BTW, the idea of the version with a Student t value is based on small-sample probabilities, not on ease of calculation.  And in what sense does it "ignore the variability"?  Did you perhaps mean to write "$\pm z\times s$" instead?